# SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException hibernate 

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have the following entity in Hibernate:

```
@Entity
public class Contact implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthday;
}
```

When I call this method of hibernate:

```
public Object get(Class entityClass, Serializable id) throws HibernateException {
    return get( entityClass.getName(), id );
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [com.mycompany.model.Contact#3]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
}
```

I tried this simple code:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("select registration_date from contact where contact_id=3");
Date i = res.getDate(1);
```

And this works fine.

What is the problem?

The type of `Date` is `java.util.Date` in both cases.

**EDITED**

I debugged it more, and saw that the exception is:

```
Bad format for DATE '517' in column 2.
```

The date there is: 1985-05-17

Comment: What is the datatype of the date-column on the database and which RDBMS is it?

Comment: @centic the type is Date and the data . What do you mean by RDMBS? i'ts mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very very silly problem.

The field name in Hibernate was `birthday` while in the db i was `registration_date`.

`birthday` in db was an int field..

Answer (score 1):

you can use notation coming along Hibernate implementation of JPA

```
@Column(name="registration_date")
private Date birthday;
```

Thus you don't have to change the DB column's name.

Cheers